# HTML5Boilerplate build script with assests sub-folders

Tags: ant, html5boilerplate, build-script

### My site layout (asset folders only):

/assets 
/assets/js 
/asstes/js/frameworks  - conatins js files like jquery.js 
/assets/js/plugins     - contains my jquery plugins

### index.html extract:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/frameworks/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.tofslaforms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.vticker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.messagebar.js"></script>
<!-- end scripts-->
```

### project.properties extract:

dir.js = assets/js 
 dir.js.libs = assets/js/libs 
 dir.css = assets/css 
 dir.images = assets/img

When I run the ant build script, all the js files under the assets/js (inclduign files in the sub-folders are deleted), and they are not included in the newly created minified file (3891a4a.js).

In the index.html file, the references remain to the original js files (e.g. ), and not to the newly created 3891a4a.js file.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - did you solve it by any luck ? I'm facing the same issue..

Comment: Did either of you end up solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you open an issue on the github project repo? https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/issues